# Using overflow:hidden on <object> tag does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and above

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, overflow, hidden

**I've this**

```
<object data="file.svg"></object>
```

**I've tried:**

Inline style

```
<object data="file.svg" style="overflow:hidden"></object>
```

CSS

```
<style>object{overflow:hidden}</style>
```

jQuery

```
$('object').css('overflow','hidden');
```

JavaScript

```
var object = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
object[0].style.overflow = "hidden";
```

Nothing works in Internet Explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: I've IE 10. I need it working in IE +9

Comment: Wrap the object in a div with overflow hidden?

Comment: m69. Doesn't work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it:**

Inner SVG must have preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice", width and height in 99% and viewBox attribute setted.

```
<object data="file.svg"></object>
```

Inner svg

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice" style="width:99%; height:99%">...</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting the height and width of the object tag element in CSS fixed the overflow issue.